# jQuery UI Dialog and Flash in IE

Tags: javascript, flash, jquery-ui, clipboard, zeroclipboard

I've been trying to get [Zero Clipboard](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/) and [jQuery UI Dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog) to play nice together, and it's proving to be rather difficult.

Zero Clipboard allows copying to clipboard from Javascript by placing a transparent Flash movie over a button, so that the user clicks on the Flash when he tried to click the button. This works nicely and cross-browser as you can see in the [demo page](http://bowser.macminicolo.net/~jhuckaby/zeroclipboard/).

However, when trying to use this in a jQuery UI Dialog box something seems to go wrong.

First, I discovered that the flash element must be placed inside the dialog element, otherwise Chrome and IE refuse to respond to click events. This means I can't use the `glue` convenience method, but that's OK.

However, now IE for some reason won't accept the `setText` method on the Flash element.

An example of what I did is [here](http://pastehtml.com/view/091008rrSJDScJ.html). My code starts around line 300, and the most relevant lines are:

```
$("#showme").dialog({autoOpen: false, width: 550, height: 200});
$("#showme").bind("dialogopen", function() {
    if($("#clipflash").length == 0) {
        var btn = $("#d_clip_button");
        $("<div id='clipflash' style='position:absolute; background: #f00; z-index: 9999' />")
            .css(btn.position())
            .width(btn.width())
            .height(btn.height())
            .html(clip.getHTML(btn.width(), btn.height()))
            .appendTo("#showme");
    }
});
```

I colored the div red so it's easier to spot and set its z-index to 9999, just to be safe. I then set the position and size to cover the "button", and add the HTML for the Flash element with `clip.getHTML()`.

I've been working on this for several hours now, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Almost forgot:** my problem is that IE7 says "Object does not support this property or method" inside the Zero Clipboard code.

#### UPDATE

powtac's comment points to something that looks really promising:

> I forgot the own golden rule:  In
>   order for the Flash ExternalInterface
>   to work in IE 7, you have to stuff the
>   EMBED/OBJECT HTML into the DIV element
>   *AFTER* it gets appended to the DOM.  Stupid IE.

However, switching the lines `.html(clip.getHTML(btn.width(), btn.height()))` and `.appendTo("#showme")` didn't help. Even doing a `setTimeout` for adding the flash HTML later did not help. I feel like I'm really close, though...

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/issues/detail?id=7#c4

Comment: Why don't you put that in an answer, so I could at least vote you up?

Answer (score 3):

OK, so powtac did point me in the right direction, but there was one element missing: using the jQuery `html()` function did not have the same effect as simply setting `innerHTML`. If would be nice if somebody could explain why.

So, the fixed code looks like this:

```
$("#showme").bind("dialogopen", function() {
    if($("#clipflash").length == 0) {
        var btn = $("#d_clip_button");
        $("<div id='clipflash' style='position:absolute; background: #f00; z-index: 9999' />")
            .css(btn.position())
            .width(btn.width())
            .height(btn.height())
            .appendTo("#showme")
            [0].innerHTML = clip.getHTML(btn.width(), btn.height());
    }
});
```

Also, I forgot to put DOCTYPE in the example page, so the offsets are wrong in IE. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

I adapted your answer to a reusable method, and fixed a few position issues (I had to add position:absolute, and use `outerWidth()` and `outerHeight()`.

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/inufik/8).

```
function setupCopier(selector, buttonSelector, callback, opt_dialogSelector){
  var copiedText = $(selector).text();
  ZeroClipboard.setMoviePath('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/464119/Programming/javascript/libraries/ZeroClipboard/ZeroClipboard.swf');
  var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
  clip.setText(copiedText);
  clip.addEventListener('complete', callback);

  $(buttonSelector).each(function(){
    clip.glue(this);
  });

  // Make sure Zero Clipboard is on top
  $("#ZeroClipboardMovie_1").
    parent().
    css("z-index", 2000);

  if (opt_dialogSelector) {
    $(opt_dialogSelector).bind("dialogopen", function() {
      if($("#clipflash").length === 0) {
        var btn = $(opt_dialogSelector).find(buttonSelector);
        $("<div id='clipflash' style='position:absolute; z-index: 9999' />")
          .css(btn.position())
          .width(btn.outerWidth())
          .height(btn.outerHeight())
          .appendTo(opt_dialogSelector)
          [0].innerHTML = clip.getHTML(btn.outerWidth(), btn.outerHeight());
      }
    });
  }
}

$(function(){
  setupCopier('#copy-div', '.copy-button', function(){
    alert("Copied");
  }, '#dialog');

  $("#open-dialog-button").click(function(){
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
  });

  $("#dialog").dialog({autoOpen: false, modal: true, resizable: false, draggable: false,
        title: "Create your Free Personal Bar now", height:200, width:300});
});
```